# Is there a way to forward a serial console access via SSH tunnel?

Tags: linux, console, ssh-tunnel

I have a physical Linux machine which have a serial console cable connected via USB-SERIAL adapter to control a network device over serial connection (115,200,n,8)

Using this Linux machine, I would like to be able to access this network device via SSH from any remote machine, so the Linux machine will forward my console access via SSH (like some sort of SSH tunnel, where part of the tunnel is SSH and other part is console):

`ANY-REMOTE-SERVER ----[SSH]----> PHYSICAL-LINUX-MACHINE ----[SERIAL CONSOLE]---->NETWORK-DEVICE`

Typically for these scenarios I use some sort of a serial console server device which expose some sort of management capabilities and SSH connectivity that forward the console access via telnet/ssh to some assigned port.

I would like to achieve this functionality, but without that physical console server.
is there any software based console server that I could use for this?

I don't want to use VNC or any other remote-control desktop solutions to access the Linux Machine. I am looking for some sort of SSH based solution that will port forward my console access.

Answer (score 0):

Look 'wards a vmware type reading of the serial output, wireshark sgot serial port monitor addons in install screen

Looking for a macOS-physical queueing serial from linux or windows (jODin/heimdall - linux) softwaren through ssh tunnel, remote vm USB/serial